# Which of the following sentence is correct?

Tags: articles, grammatical-number

1. you can make a mixture of 50 pills of aspirin and 50 pills of antibiotics for $120.
2. you can make a mixtures of 50 pills of aspirin and 50 pills of antibiotics for $120.

Comment: Which one do you think is correct? We can give you more help if we understand why you're having trouble figuring out the answer.

Comment: *A* is singular. *Mixtures* is plural. You do the math. I think this is really too basic even for this site.

Comment: i know what is singular and plural thank you for your response. I just want to know your idea about this because a friend of mine corrected me that the correct sentence should be the first one which i know is wrong.

Comment: Why do you think the first sentence is incorrect even though your friend thinks it is correct?

Comment: I'm having confusion when using singular and plural in a sentence.

Comment: @ЯegDwight: Wouldn't it be better to remove the offending "**a**" in the second example, and focus on what I assume the question is *really* about? By which I mean using singular/plural *mixture/mixtures*, both of which are grammatical. That's certainly a distinction which might reasonably be asked about here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes, but we can't guess what the question is really about. We can only take it at face value. If it was a mere typo, then the OP could have fixed it within minutes. But it's still there, so we can't be sure. I *have* seen questions, and so have you, actually asking whether it should be "a red car" or "a red cars". (Also, if the question *is* about *mixture/mixtures*, then it's still too basic, just in a different way: does the OP mean one or several? Again, we can't know that. How many mixtures *can* you make for $120?)

Comment: @ЯegDwight: You're right. we're entitled to expect (a) evidence of prior research, and (b) irrelevant typos to be edited out by the OP. If indeed they *are* mere "typos", which may not be the case here (apparently the context is OP *buying* a mixture, not making up one or more in a "production process"). If someone had told Henry Ford they knew how he could make **a** car for less than $1000 (as opposed to **an indefinite number of cars**), he might have decided there wasn't enough profit in a single sale! :)

Answer (score 4):

> 1) You can make **a mixture** of 50 pills of aspirin and 50 pills of antibiotics for $120.

If you are just making one "group", this statement is OK. The "group" is 50+50 pills combined, but are still just one group (a mixture). *the* could also be OK if referring to a specific group.

2) can be plural but without the article.

> 2) You can make **mixtures** of 50 pills of aspirin and 50 pills of antibiotics for $120.

Let's say you are making 10 of these mixtures. Then this phrase is OK.

So which one is best depends on context.

Comment: thank you for your response much appreciated. The scenario is getting a specials or discount. For example, If i purchase 50 pills for a regular price it will cost me $80 either of the products, but if i will take advantage of the promo i can save $40. So, we corrected each other on the sentence that was mentioned above:))))

Comment: You might want to add such information to your question. It may be enough to reopen it.